# Migrate/Copy Discussion From one Stack community to other Stack Community

Tags: discussion

I have raised a question on the wrong site/ In the discussion, they said to post the question in other stack community How can I migrate/ transfer/copy question to other Stack Community.

Comment: Some communities have a flag reason for 'belongs on another site', and you can tell the mods which site. If a particular site doesn't, or if the appropriate site isn't listed, flag for generic moderator attention, and indicate that you believe the question should be migrated, and to which site.

Answer (score 7):

**Cross-posting is bad!**

Please don't do it.

Cross-posting is where you copy the content of your question from one site and paste it into another site and ask a new question. Again, please do not do this, ever.

If you ask a question on the wrong site, it is better to ask a moderator (via the flag system) to migrate the question to another site. There are many reasons why this is a good thing:

- The moderator who's about to migrate your question will be able to check your question for quality. There's a rule of etiquette across the Stack Exchange network of "Don't Migrate Crap", which means that posts that are low-effort and do not include sufficient details to be answerable are not migrated, but rather must be improved or closed. If the moderator is especially generous, they will edit your question to improve it prior to migration.
- Migration provides an audit trail that makes it clear where the question was originally asked. For instance, **this question** itself got migrated from superuser.com to meta.superuser.com, our site for questions *about* Super User.
- Migration provides the community receiving your question with the ability to *reject* the migration, which closes your question and marks it as migration rejected. The rejected migration provides very valuable information to Super User's own moderators and/or migration voting community (depending on how your question got migrated), which allows us to improve our migration decisions in the future.
- Cross-posting will lead to your question being analyzed and worked on *twice* on two different sites, duplicating effort. Someone who takes time to write an answer on one community will be upset to have wasted their time if they find that someone else already put in the effort to solve your question on another community.
- Sometimes your question will get helpful comments or even complete answers on the site you asked it on, even if it belongs on a different site. All of these useful comments and answers will be transferred with your question over to the correct site, which reduces the amount of work the receiving site has to do to finish your question.

If someone gave you advice on Super User in the comments that suggested that you ought to cross-post, **they're wrong**, and you shouldn't listen to them. Never, ever cross-post.

Comment: I'm a mod and... I have literally nothing to add. This kinda covers everything I'd say, and then the stuff I missed.